# How I test a middleware that receives receives args?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jestjs

I have the following middleware:

```
function check(expectedKeys: string[], req: Request): boolean{
  if (expectedKeys.length !== Object.keys(req.body).length) return false;

  for (const key of expectedKeys) {
    if (!(key in req.body)) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

export default function checkRequestBodyKeys(expectedKeys: string[]) {
  return (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const isValid = check(expectedKeys, req);

    if (isValid) return next();
    
    return res.status(Status.BadRequest).json({status: Status.BadRequest, error: ErrorMessage.InvalidRequestBody});
  }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import postAuth from "../controllers/auth.controller";
import checkRequestBodyKeys from "../middlewares/checkRequestBodyKeys.middleware"

export const authRoute = Router();

authRoute.post("/", checkRequestBodyKeys(["email", "password"]), postAuth);
```

I want to test if it returns the expected values (res with args and next). I know how to test and mock the functions of a simple middleware, but this type I have no idea how to implement.

I am trying to write something like this, but I know that it doesn't make any sense:

```
describe("validateRequestBody middleware", () => {
  let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
  let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
  let nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {};
    mockResponse = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      json: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  test('short name should return error', async () => {
    const expectedResponse = [{error: "Invalid name"}];
    mockRequest = {
      body: {
        name: "aa",
        email: "test@yahoo.com",
        password: "###!!!AAAbbb111222"
      }
    }

    const check = checkRequestBodyKeys(
      ["name", "email", "password"]
    );

    expect( checkRequestBodyKeys(["name", "email", "password"]) ).toEqual(Function)
  });
});
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

checkRequestBodyKeys returns a function that is the actual middleware wich is used by express. That returned function must be executed with the mocked req, res and next. So then you can check if they, or the function inside them, were called with the parameters you expected.

```
describe("validateRequestBody middleware", () => {
  let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
  let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
  let nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRequest = {};
    mockResponse = {
      status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      json: jest.fn(),
    };
  });

  test('short name should return error', async () => {
    const expectedResponse = {status: 400, error: "Invalid name"};
    mockRequest = {
      body: {
        name: "aa",
        email: "test@yahoo.com",
        password: "###!!!AAAbbb111222"
      }
    }

    const check = checkRequestBodyKeys(
      ["name", "email", "password"]
    );

    expect( check ).toEqual( expect.any(Function) )

    // The middleware is called
    check(mockRequest, mockResponse, nextFunction)
    // And here you check if the res.json function was called with certain parameters
    expect( mockResponse.json ).toBeCalledWith(expectedResponse)
  });
});
```

Comment: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality  
Expected: [Function Function]  
Received: [Function anonymous]

Comment: Oh right, actually it should be `expect( check ).toEqual( expect.any(Function) )`, i'll edit it

Comment: expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected), 
    Expected: {"error": "Invalid name", "status": 400}, 
    Number of calls: 0
For some reason neither status nor json weren't called. I have no ideia whats is going on here. Thanks for your help